# Batch / BAT - Change proxy settings with a batch / BAT file

Tags: proxy, batch-file, settings

Could someone teach me please how to change proxy settings with a .bat file, or a suggestion?
Honestly I can't find good information about.

I need a .bat file which will change my internet settings (Proxy) with a specific proxy ip and port.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proxy server settings for Internet Explorer are stored in the registry under `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

With [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-windows-powershell) (included with Windows since Windows 7) you could use:

`set-itemproperty -path "hkcu:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -name ProxyServer -value "http=proxy-url:port;https=proxy-url:port;ftp=proxy-url:port;socks=proxy-url:port;" -type string`

This setting will only affect Internet Explorer and may require a new tab or maybe even a restart of IE, although that's unlikely.

Comment: Set-ItemProperty : Missing an argument for parameter 'Name'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
At line:1 char:91
+ ... rnet Settings" -name
+                    ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand

Answer (score 9):

Another option, if you don't want install Powershell, is to use the command [REG.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20160308052738/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx?mfr=true).

So, in that case you should  add in your batch script:

`REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer  /d "http=proxy-url:port;https=proxy-url:port;ftp=proxy-url:port;socks=proxy-url:port;" /t REG_SZ /f`

For information, the proxy Internet Explorer settings are also used by Google Chrome

Comment: On win32 Chrome/Chromium will use the IE proxy settings (i.e. system settings) `unless` you specify a proxy on the command line, for example `chrome.exe" --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:9090"` or  -`proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: How to add username & password for private proxy?

Comment: Let me add that, unlike most registry settings, this one is working with no delay. You double click your batch script and it's instantly applied. If you also want to ENABLE proxy, add this line: `REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f`